# mercurial-reviewboard plugin no longer working with TortoiseHg 2.4.3

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, review-board

I had just barely gotten the Mercurial-Reviewboard plugin working with TortoiseHG 2.4.2 when I upgraded to TortoiseHG 2.4.3 and it stopped working.
It's now throwing the following error when I click the "Post Review" button.
"postreview plugin version 4.1.0"
"'module' object has no attribute 'findoutgoing'"

I've tried many different branches of the plugin and have had zero luck.  The one I have right now is Fredrik Haard's and can be found here:https://bitbucket.org/haard/mercurial-reviewboard
Unfortunately he hasn't updated it in some time.

I've tried looking through the source for the plugin but know next to nothing about Python in general and Mercurial plugins in specific.

If anyone can help in any way I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I will be fixing this since I have the same problem, can't promise a target date, but can promise I'll try to get it done ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same error `"'module' object has no attribute 'findoutgoing'"`, using the following:
**TortoiseHG**: 2.4.3 (with Mercurial-2.3.2, Python-2.7.3, PyQt-4.9.3, Qt-4.8.2)
**Reviewboard**: 1.6.13
**Mercurial-reviewboard plugin**: windix-mercurial-reviewboard (4.1.0) from 2012-08-30 and with the following change in reviewboard.py at line 400:

```
self._api_post('/account/login/', {
```

instead of

```
self._api_post('/api/json/accounts/login/', {
```

I only have a local repository, towards which Reviewboard points using the path on the disk.
**The problem was fixed** as soon as I added in the `.hg/hgrc` file of that repository, the following:

```
[paths]
default = http://localhost:8003
```

where 8003 is the port I configured for the same repo, in the same file inside that repo.
I have two more local repos, in the same situation - no remote base - configured for 8000 and 8005 respectively, I am now able to post review requests from the TortoiseHG user interface for all of them (after having added for each of these repos, the [paths] section and the default url like above).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

While still having some problems, 'my' fork works for me right now although there are encoding errors for source files that are non-ascii. If it does not work for you (commit from 2012-24-10), and the problems you have are not related to encoding (working on those), could you please describe what is happening/provide log messages?